# (Angular) Ngx-tiptap. Add different classes to headings based on their level

Tags: html, angular, editor, tiptap

I'm currently working on a project using the ngx-tiptap library in Angular, and I'm facing an issue with applying custom classes to headings. I want each heading level (H1, H2, H3, etc.) to have a different styling class (e.g., h1-style, h2-style, h3-style, etc.).

In Vue.js, I came across a solution that worked, but I'm having trouble implementing it in Angular. Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
editor = newEditor({
  extensions: [
    StarterKitHeading.configure({
      levels: [1, 2, 3]
    }),
    Paragraph.configure({
      HTMLAttributes: {
        class: 'p-style'
      }
    }),
    Blockquote.configure({
      HTMLAttributes: {
        class: 'blockquote-style'
      }
    })
  ],
  content: '<p>I think where I am not, therefore I am where I do not think.</p>'
});
```

I expected the configure method of StarterKitHeading to allow me to specify custom classes for each heading level, similar to the class attribute in Paragraph and Blockquote. However, this approach doesn't seem to work in Angular.

Could someone please guide me on how to apply custom classes to each heading level using ngx-tiptap in Angular?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Classes on heading elements based on the level are not configurable in the official Tiptap extension, you'll need to create your own extension for that or better extend the offical extension and make changes that you want to support.

`renderHTML` method is responsible for, well, "rendering" the DOM for a node or a mark. You can extend the Heading extension and ovverride the `renderHTML` method like below -

```js
import { mergeAttributes } from "@tiptap/core";
import { Heading as TipTapHeading } from "@tiptap/extension-heading";

export const Heading = TipTapHeading.extend({
  renderHTML({ node, HTMLAttributes }) {
    const hasLevel = this.options.levels.includes(node.attrs.level);
    const level = hasLevel ? node.attrs.level : this.options.levels[0];

    return [
      `h${level}`,
      mergeAttributes(this.options.HTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes, {
        class: `h${node.attrs.level}-style`,
      }),
      0,
    ];
  },
});
```

Notice that I have added `class` attribute with the desired value.

Now add this new extension in the editor configuration like below, don't forget to disable the heading extension from the `StarterKit` -

```js
const initialContent = `
<p>Hello World!</p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
`;

const editor = useEditor({
  extensions: [
    Heading,
    StarterKit.configure({
      heading: false,
    }),
  ],
  content: initialContent,
});
```

You can find the complete working demo on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tiptap-customized-heading-extension-std8zz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A2%2C22).

These snippets and codesandbox project are written with React but these parts  are common everywhere.

Additionally, you can check out custom extension documentation [here](https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions).